# How do I wire this ceiling lamp?

Tags: electrical, wire, lamp

I have this metal ceiling lamp but it have two earth wires, one for the holder on the ceiling and one for the cover of the bulb, and I don't know if I have to connect them to the house wires or just leave them... can you explain me what to do with them?

[image: this is the entire lamp]

[image: in one side it is the socket with 3 wires, one of them have a distintive yellow thread and in the other side are the out wires that I ahve to connect]

[image: the yellow wire that correspond to the earth of the holder]

Comment: All those things need grounding.

Answer (score 2):

You're meant to wire nut both fixture grounds together, and connected them to the 3rd wire ground on the circuit.